# How do I sort these values using Bash Script in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, duplicates

```
-53 45
-54 43
-55 42
-56 41
-57 40
-59 37
-61 35
-61 36
-62 34
-64 33
-65 31
-65 32
-67 30
-68 29
-69 28
-72 25
-73 23
-73 24
-74 22
-76 20
-76 22
-78 20
-79 18
-80 17
-81 16
```

In the above you will see that at -61 occurs twice and so do some other values. I want to just create a new file without any duplicates. So the new file should have either -61 35 or -61 36 ...

How do I do that?! I tried using sort using uniq but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a file called input

```
cat input | sort -u -n
```

When doing a numeric (-n) sort along with unique (-u), the duplicate checking is achieved.

Comment: No need for `cat`: `sort -nu input`

Comment: [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).  Otherwise, this is definitely *my* preferred solution.

Comment: I do agree the use of cat is unnecessary here.  In this case I was using it as an illustration of getting the data into the sort command.  In practice I would advocate simply piping the output of whatever process generates this list into the sort command.  I will make that clearer in the future.

Answer (score 4):

If you can guarantee the length of the first field,

```
sort | uniq --check-chars=4
```

will do the trick.

Otherwise, try awk:

```
awk '{ if (FNR == 1 || last != $1) print; last = $1; }'
```